# the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated 5.7 0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, email, smtp

I want to send an email from my app using Visual Basic.

1. I gave access to the less secure app option on my sender email.
2. I tried to enable 2 factor-authenticator and also to use an App password.
3. I also changed my e-mail password into a stronger one.

I literally tried everything I found on internet but still can't fix my problem.
Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim smtp_server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage
            smtp_server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtp_server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword")
            smtp_server.Port = 587
            smtp_server.EnableSsl = True
            smtp_server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = New MailAddress(Txtfrom.Text)
            e_mail.To.Add(Txtto.Text)
            e_mail.Subject = Txtsub.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            e_mail.Body = Txtmess.Text
            smtp_server.Send(e_mail)
            MsgBox("email sent thank you")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Before sending an Email (assuming you're using the two-factor AUTH with an App Password that is correctly registered and verified), print to the Output pane: `Console.Writeline(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol)`. See what that is (if it's not `Tls12`, then you know why). -- You should also mention what .Net version you're using.

Comment: Forgot to mention it, I am using .Net 5.0

Comment: Well I just found out that  there is no needed to add a securityprotocol for .net 5.0 in windows 10. 
I just enabled TLS 1.3 from windows control panel and now the error has gone, although I still got a new error "Failure senting the email", but that's a progress I guess :)

Thank you for your help! You made me search about the security protocol :)

Comment: You cannot use TLS13. Make sure TLS12 is the default. Also, make sure - as mentioned -  that you have enabled your App Password correctly. -- Note that [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) is deprecated (see the Ramarks section), because of its use of [`STARTTLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl). Possibly, use a different Mail Client (as also suggested in the MSDN Docs).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 'Txtfrom.Text' is your email address.

```
smtp_server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword")
...
e_mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail")
```